# Notifications for rejected suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications

I recently am making quite a bit of suggested edits, especially to tag wikis. While most of the time the suggested edits are approved, there is a small number of them that can get rejected (I am okay with it anyway).

However, I noticed that there isn't a notification regarding a suggested edit being rejected. The only way I am doing now is to go through a series of links before seeing the statistics of my account showing the number of approved and rejected suggested edits, and doing the arithmetic to see if the recent suggested edits has been approved or rejected.

Is it possible that such a notification be implemented so that we can be notified of rejected suggested edits and perhaps improve on them based on optional comments by the person rejecting the suggested edit?

Comment: feature request has been asked on [metase] as well [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624)

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing me to the correct direction. Will be analyzing the discussions there soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been asked and discussed at quite some length on Meta already.

[Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

[Jeff's answer:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123439/148203)

> I understand the desire to educate, but there is something deeply
>   wrong about the proposed design.
>
> The net effect is the user seeing this broadcast in their face in the
>   most obtrusive way we can:
>
> You've done something wrong. Click here to learn why you suck.
>
> You should only send the user obtrusive 'in-your-face' messages about
>   how awesome they are.
>
> Messages about non-awesomeness should always be delivered quietly, via
>   a backchannel, in a way that minimizes their impact. Otherwise, we're
>   slapping them in the face.

Comment: But can't such a feature be added as an opt-in basis?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you don't get notifications on rejected edit. Still, you can check your recent suggested edits on your profile page. (You just have to choose [suggestions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on the activity tab.)

If you want them split to approved/rejected/pending edits you could play around with [SEDE](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). (With the obvious disadvantage, that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week.) For example, here are your [approved](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1326992/approved-rejected-pending-suggested-edits-by-the-given-user?userid=30610&appr=1&rej=0) and [rejected](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1326992/approved-rejected-pending-suggested-edits-by-the-given-user?userid=30610&appr=0&rej=1) edits. And it seems that you had no [pending](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1326992/approved-rejected-pending-suggested-edits-by-the-given-user?userid=30610&appr=0&rej=0) edits at the time when SEDE was last updated.)

On a healthy site, typically suggested edits are quite quickly reviewed, so if the review works fast, the lack of notification isn't that much of a problem. (You simply check your past edits maybe once a few days.) Probably the exception are the edits to the tag-info, since on smaller sites there aren't enough users who are allowed to review them. In the following queries, you can check what are the longest times between the suggested edit and the approval/rejection [on posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/942645/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-posts?num=100) and [on tag-infos](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100). On meta, you only have [suggested edits for tag-info](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.webapps/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100). (I will add that some cases where you see rather long time between the suggested edit and the final decision are not caused by lack of reviewers, but simply because the OP decided to reverse the decision of the reviewers a few month later.)

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your suggested tag wiki edits:

The tag wiki's should help people decide whether or not they need to include that tag on their question.

While having a definition of what the tag *is* might be important for some of the more obscure web applications it should not be the entirety of the wiki.

You should include details of how the tag should be used on the site and perhaps even details of how the tag shouldn't be used.

Comment: Ah, I try as much as I can to add information regarding how questions can be asked, though most of the time everything related to the tag is on-topic

Comment: @Hydra - yeah. Writing tag wiki's is hard. I struggle with them myself.